# How to make json post request?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, jsonresponse

I have to make json post request with the following request parameters,

```
{   
    "method":"login", 
    "data":{  
        "username":"korea", 
        "password":"123456" 
    } 
}
```

I use the following code to make the request,

```
NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{""\"\method:\"\login\"\"\,""\data:\"{\"\"username\":\"%@\",\"password\":\"%@\"}",username,password];
    NSLog(@"Request: %@", jsonRequest);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl..."];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody: requestData];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I have to get the response but Im not be able to get the response

Comment: have u checked with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15749527/5362916

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516823/create-a-json-string-in-objective-c

Comment: yeah I have tried those examples yet the problem persists

Comment: Does your connection fail? What error do you receive?

Comment: @StanlyMoses http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767908/volunteermatch-api-objective-c/33886449#33886449
Use this class for comon method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    NSDictionary *objectDic = @{@"username" : username, @"password" : password};
    NSDictionary *dataDic = @{@"data" : objectDic};
    NSDictionary *methodDic = @{@"method" : @"login", @"data": dataDic};

    NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:methodDic
                                               options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                 error:nil];
    [request setHTTPBody: requestData];
```